# Simple navigation bar not working in IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I've made a horizontal navigation bar to go on my website and it's not displaying correctly in IE6.

It's a really simple navigation bar and I'm not aware 100% what works and what doesn't in IE6.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my CSS?

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div id="controlslider">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#slider2">Work, Life: Balanced.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slider3">Mobilise your workforce.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slider4">Built for business.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slider5">Work whenever, wherever.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slider6">Where to buy.</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#controlslider{
    width: 981px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/images/respmod_menu.gif) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: -25px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#controlslider ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#controlslider li{
display: inline-block !important;
padding: 5px 0px 0 0;
width: 190px;
height: 35px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#controlslider li a{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color : white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block !important;
    width: 190px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#controlslider li a:hover{
    background: url(http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/images/respmod_menu_button.png);
    width: 190px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `block` and `float` instead of `inline-block`.

```
#controlslider li{
   display: block !important;
   float: left;
   padding: 5px 0px 0 0;
   width: 190px;
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Be sure to clear floating after the `UL`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it shows up ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/PVS5B/7/ but still no luck with anything showing correctly in IE6 :-(

Comment: @Tim Mind taking a screenshot of what is wrong with your ie6? i used netrenderer on this jsfiddle and i saw nothing wrong or different

Comment: @Lollero Here is a screengrab I just took http://i.imgur.com/MhTRP.jpg -  The navigation bar is right at the bottom. Done the test using Adobe Browserlab as I'm on a Mac.

Comment: @Tim I suggest that you'd try to compare everything you have here really well http://www.jsfiddle.net/PVS5B/7 to the code/site youre trying to fix because im not getting any problems testing that out in ie6 or any other browser no matter how i look at it. On another note, do you experience this on every browser or just ie? Cause im thinking this is not a problem thats just on IE. I believe that this is just matter of paddings and maybe height values and margins. Are you familiar with firebug or other browsers developer tools?

Comment: @Tim May be a problem with the Adobe viewer? Here is a [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/y2uNK.jpg) from my IE6 in a VM. Menu looks fine.

Comment: @Tim & @DanielB before i wrote my last comment i also tested the jsfiddle version 7 in adobe browserlab as well and so there was nothing weird there.

Answer (score 0):

Im puzzled by your two negative margins.

At least the first one seems to have some logic as you seem to be using it for moving the menu up, but you should never fix problems with negative margins.

The second negative margin just makes no sense to me as it screw up the menu.

Things are not showing properly at least because of those two negative margins that you have. ( not saying its the problem in your question necessarily, but it sure is a problem. )

You should get rid of these.

```
#controlslider{
        margin-top: -25px;
}
#controlslider ul{
        margin-left: -36px;
}
```

Edit: I would like to note that im all in for using negative margins. The thing just is that if code can be fixed by refining your code it is not very productive to fix it with negative margins. Which may even result some problems.